# Optimize Pandas df for counting positional-char-frequency across list of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm creating a pandas dataframe for tracking frequency of chars, ***at each position***, in a given list of words. However, the run-time is brutally slow for larger lists + longer words (algo is running with O(n^2) due to nested loops)

Does anyone have an optimization for the algo or could point me to a vectorized-type function already optimized for something like this?

**Reprex:**

```
import pandas as pd

word_list = ['despairing','stationary','presenting','copernicus','wheelchair']
word_length = len(word_list[0])

letters  = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
positions = ["pos" + f"{x}" for x in range(1, word_length+1)]

count_matrix = pd.DataFrame(0, columns = positions, index = letters)

for word in range(0, len(word_list)):
    for letter in range(0, word_length):
        count_matrix.loc[word_list[word][letter], f'pos{letter+1}'] += 1

count_matrix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `f2(...)` is an improvement over your original algorithm. (`f1(...)` is your algorithm, wrapped up into a function.)

While both of our functions loop through both words and letters, this is actually `O(n*k)` where n is the number of words and k is the maximum length of your words. You have to process each letter in each word, so there isn't really a way around that runtime. But, I think `f2(...)` has a few improvements that speed up the execution, including not creating the DataFrame until after processing all of the letters. (I think that finding and editing individual values in a pandas DataFrame is generally slow and discouraged.)

This new function also words for any lengths of words (while your original function won't capture any character positions for words longer than the first word).

In ipython or Jupyter notebooks you can run `%timeit f1(word_list)` and `%timeit f2(word_list)` to see how long each function takes to run.

```py
import pandas as pd

def f1(word_list):
    word_length = len(word_list[0])

    letters  = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    positions = ["pos" + f"{x}" for x in range(1, word_length+1)]

    count_matrix = pd.DataFrame(0, columns = positions, index = letters)

    for word in range(0, len(word_list)):
        for letter in range(0, word_length):
            count_matrix.loc[word_list[word][letter], f'pos{letter+1}'] += 1

    return count_matrix

def f2(word_list):
    d = {}
    letters  = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    for letter in letters:
        d[letter] = {}
    for word in word_list:
        for i, letter in enumerate(word):
            if i not in d[letter]:
                d[letter][i] = 1
            else:
                d[letter][i] += 1
    
    count_matrix = pd.DataFrame(d)

    # making the DataFrame resemble your output
    count_matrix = count_matrix.sort_index()
    count_matrix = count_matrix.T
    count_matrix = count_matrix.fillna(0)
    count_matrix = count_matrix.astype(int)
    count_matrix.columns = ["pos" + str(col+1) for col in count_matrix.columns]

    return count_matrix
```